# NSDate from String for eventkit

Tags: swift

I have a swift app that allows users to store events in the default calendar. Everything seems to be working fine except 1 part. I allow users to set a start and end date from a date picker. The format is is

```
Sunday 21 Aug, 11:05 pm
```

I had a save button which takes this date and I am trying to convert it to a valid NSDate using

```
let startDate = "\(txtStartDate.text!)"
let endDate = "\(txtEndDate.text!)"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMM, h:mm a"

event.title = "\(txtEventTitle.text!)"
event.startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(startDate)!
event.endDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(endDate)!
event.notes = "\(txtNotes.text!)"
event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
```

But for some reason it wont save the event. If I change the start date to

```
event.startDate = NSDate()
```

everything works great so I know it is saving.

Not sure what I am missing with the conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that's what Playgrounds are for ...

Copy and paste the code into a Playground and you will see that the date formatter returns `nil` for the given string and date format.

The issue is the locale. You have to set the locale explicitly to `en_US_POSIX` to ensure that the code works independent of the current locale.

Source : [Technical Q&A QA1480 NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

```
let startDate = "Sunday 21 Aug, 11:05 pm"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE dd MMM, h:mm a"

let eventStartDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(startDate)!
```